# Correct update logic

Tags: android, mysql

I have an application which has a database. DB is updated downloading from the server xml.I want to understand the logic of the update. My ways I was not correct.Here are my ways:

1. You use a single link to Xml. Xml will be updated. It will only store a new record. 
   Outcome: user missed what the update does not get it.
2. Each xml will hold a reference to the following xml. Outcome: user missed a lot of xml will have the download process and will not know when will the update.
3. Xml will store all the records for all the time, but then after a while it becomes very large. Result of heavy traffic

Please tell me the correct update logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go this way.

1. I would keep track of the updating process. like saving last updated date or else a version of update.
2. When I send the request to the server I would send this date or the version number along with the request (POST or GET method).
3. Now depending on the date or version I would get the XML file from the server. Then I will update the contents.
4. If user is new then there will be no date or version parameter sent to server. Then the complete XML would come. If they will to update from first, then you can go with updating part by part with your own way(like regular intervals of time) till the current version of update is reached if you concern about traffic.Then from there you can continue. Again you can keep track of date or version number and start updating process as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put some logic on your the server:

- Application asks the server for updates, sending current database version as a parameters
- Server check the application database version against the latest one, and compute the list of changes that occured
- Server reply to the application by sending all theses changes, so the application can update its database content (along with its database version)